# PHP preg_match (_all) for text range

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

trying to get Textrange (n words before and after) a search string (myself)

```
$text = 'Me, my dog and “myself“ are going on a vacation. Irene and myself are broke. Myself is here :P John and myself!';

 preg_match_all("/(?:[^ ]+ ){0,2}(?:[“'"(‘. ])myself(?:[“'")‘. ])(?: [^ ]+){0,2}/", $text, $matches);
```

this gives me matches :

• dog and “myself“ are going

•  myself

**But it should be:**

• dog and “myself“ are going

• Irene and myself are broke

• John and myself!

Please help me find all matches as text range 2 words before and 2 words after.
no matter if there is a special char or whitespace before or after search string (myself) or 'myself' or “myself“ ...

thanks.Sepp

Comment: you want to get two word before "myself" and two word after "myself" ?

Comment: yes. no matter if there is a special char or whitespace before or after.

Comment: Does it have to be regex?

Comment: yes it has to be regex

Comment: Any kind of regex or only preg_match?

Comment: it should be preg_match .... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises due to the fact that both `[“'"(‘. ]` and `[“'")‘. ]` are obligatory and require one char to be there before and after `myself`. Then, there must also be another space before and after `myself` required by `(?:[^ ]+ ){0,2}` and `(?: [^ ]+){0,2}`.

You may use

```
'/(?:\S+\s+){0,2}(?:[“'"(‘.])?myself(?:[“'")‘.]?)(?:\s+\S+){0,2}/u'
```

Or allow any punctuation around `myself` with `\p{P}`:

```
'/(?:\S+\s+){0,2}\p{P}?myself\p{P}?(?:\s+\S+){0,2}/u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zX57D7/1)

Note that `(?:[“'"(‘.])?` and `(?:[“'")‘.]?)` (or `\p{P}?`) are all optional, the `?` quantifier after them makes the regex engine match only 1 or 0 occurrences of these patterns. So, if it is there or not, the match occurs.

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/A2fiB):

```
$text = 'Me, my dog and “myself“ are going on a vacation. Irene and myself are broke. Myself is here :P John and myself!';
if (preg_match_all('/(?:\S+\s+){0,2}\p{P}?myself\p{P}?(?:\s+\S+){0,2}/u', $text, $result)) {
    print_r($result[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => dog and “myself“ are going
    [1] => Irene and myself are broke.
    [2] => John and myself!
)
```

Comment: as far as i see thats working as expected. thanks a lot! sepp.